# QuadTreeProvider and WFS data

Tags: cesiumjs

With each passing day I'm getting more and more annoyed with Cesium.
There was a [project](https://github.com/vmora/cesium-buildings/) that used QuadTreeProvider to create 3D structures from WFS data.

But the Cesium guys saw the 3D stuff was more lucrative and not only created difficulties to create WFS primitives but created mechanisms to avoid all types of use other than its "Ion 3D tiles".

Now, any kind of [question involving 3D](https://community.cesium.com/t/does-quadtreeprimitive-still-support-in-cesium-1-32/5422/3) they answer with a commercial answer like:

> "That sounds like the ideal use case for 3DTiles except for the
> dynamic data. Depending on your needs and resources, you could always
> contact Todd at todd@agi.com to talk about possibly getting your data
> working with 3DTiles."

Of course we can contact Todd. But I don't want to! I want to use free 3D stuff. I WANT to use Geoserver WFS data Todd. Can you allow this for me? Can you allow [this project](https://github.com/vmora/cesium-buildings/) to work again as before?

If you want to make money from your products, you have every right to do so, but don't stop users from creating their own solutions if they don't want to contact Todd.

**After all, my question is: How can I use WFS data from Geoserver to create 3D objects in Cesium without  need to use Ion / 3DTiles ?**

Comment: I'll try to say this delicately, and I apologize if my tone comes across poorly on the Internet here.  Developing software, even open-source software, costs a ton of money.  The Cesium folks are a very friendly group of highly talented developers who recently (June 2019) launched their own company, trying to make a living doing what they love.  Todd and AGI are not part of their picture any longer.  If you like the software they produce, please consider ways to support their efforts to keep going in this pandemic.

Comment: I am not underestimating the work of the staff. I just wish they didn't take away our opportunity to choose between paid solutions (Ion) and solutions created collaboratively by the community. They are systematically preventing the community from creating alternatives to 3DTiles. No need to apologize. I understood your POV. I need to apologize because here is not the place for angry.